# Why the memoryless Markov Property is desirable

Tags: panel-data, markov-process

The memoryless Markov property says future predictions only depend on the current status.

With longitudinal data, we have all the past data recorded. Why cannot we make use of all the info? Why should we use Markov chains? Thx

Comment: If you don't believe the Markov assumption is valid for your problem, then you might be better suited to explicitly model the long-term dependency (which will increase the complexity of estimating your model). But the Markov assumption is nice as a simplifying assumption about the data generating process, and makes inference simpler as well.

Comment: Not having to use the entire, potentially very complex, past history of the data is a *huge* simplification!

Comment: With longitudinal data, observations can only be observed at certain time points e.g. follow-ups. Can the memoryless property be a reason so that we don't have to care about those unobserved states but the latest state only? –